# How can I display a byte array as a String in java's debug detail formatter?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I'd like to write a simple detail formatter that displays `byte[]` data in the form of a `String` (using `String.<init>([B)` to do the dirty work).

However, I'm not sure how to find the class name for `[B` to use when creating the formatter.  Is this even possible?  Or, alternatively, is there another way to view byte arrays as strings in the debugger?

Comment: If there was a single method that did what you want, what would its inputs and outputs be?

Comment: Suppose I have a byte array: [65, 66, 67] I would expect to get "ABC" (did I get the case right?  My ASCII-fu is weak...)

Comment: Indeed byte[] cannot be used as a key for detail formatters, but you could consider filing an enhancement request at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=JDT component Debug, since the idea makes sense. Also shipping a hexdump option with JDT sounds reasonable. You may want to search whether such request already exists in bugzilla.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't know how to get eclipse's detail formatter to automagically display byte arrays as Strings, but you can display a particular byte array by adding `new String(byteArray)` as a watch expression.

Comment: +1 you can't display a byte array as a string, but your method is the closest thing to what the question is looking for

Comment: Take care with character encoding. The `new String(bytes)` will use platform default character encoding which may not per se be the correct character encoding.

Answer (score 3):

If your question is how would I get a string representation of a byte array of [0,1,2] to be "[0,1,2]", I would suggest you take a look at Arrays.toString(byte[])

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(byte[])

Comment: Nope, I want to interpret the bytes as UTF-8 string data.

Comment: More specifically, I want to use Eclipse's detail formatter to do it.

Answer (score 2):

In Idea debug mode, right click the `byte[] data` you want to view and choose the **View Text** or **View as String**.

[image]

or you can click **Evaluate Expression**
[image]

, and decode from Base64 format.
[image]

Comment: That isn’t a string, that is just the contents of the byte array.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add Detail Formatters for simple Datatypes like `byte`.

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[].class
```

Comment: That tells me the class, but doesn't allow me to format the byte array as a string.

Any idea how to get from here to there?

Answer (score 0):

The [B type can be retrieved with byte[].class.